# State change when back button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-mobile

I'm implementing search function on my project. I have three text boxes and a search button

1. Fist Name
2. Second Name
3. Age

Search button generate search on another result page. The problem is that, when I click back button from the result page, Then the Age text box filled with first Name data which I enter previously and first name field remains empty. How did it happen.

Comment: what are the possibilities to happen

Comment: Kindly add the html snippet in your question, so others can help.